# In Eclipse, what is the definition of "workspace root"?

Tags: eclipse, variables, filepath

The concept of "workspace root" is used in many place in Eclipse, but almost always in meta terms.

However, I have looked around and I have not been able to find a formal definition of "workspace root".

1. Is it the same as the workspace?
   (e.g. is the diretory aWorkspace the "workspace root"?)

[image: C:\Users\johnk\Eclipse Workspaces\aWorkSpace]

2. Or is "Eclipse Workspaces" the "workspace root" of aWorkspace?
   (e.g **C:\Users\johnk\Eclipse Workspaces**)
3. Or is it some directory higher in the hierarchy containing aWorkSpace?

I need this definition in order to deal with my insecurity about the  meaning in the following context:

[image: The resource relative to the wokrkspace root]

It's a simple problem but at age 75, I sometimes can't get a handle on simple things that are new to me, and there are many unknowns to do the simple tests that would answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The term's usage is pulled from the doc for the [IWorkspaceRoot](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIWorkspaceRoot.html) Java interface representing the "root" of the resource hierarchy, and based on the "root" node as described for a common [tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)).

You pretty much had it figured out. Keep in mind that the *resource* hierarchy won't always be reflected by the directory and file hierarchy under the workspace's location--you can locate your projects and files anywhere.